# Two divs aligned vertically next to an image

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, fluid-layout

I want to have an avatar image with two divs on its right that are vertically aligned to it.

https://jsbin.com/qafiroquve/1/edit?html,css,output

I've read so many posts about this, but none of them seems to help me.

What is the best approach to having the image on the left with 30% of the main div's (`header`) width, and the `info` div with 70% of it?

If either of the `info` divs (`name` or `position`) has too much text, I want the `info` div to get vertically aligned to the image on its left.
I also want this `info` div to have a margin with the image.

I've tried so many options: `float: left` on `avatar` div, `display: inline-block` on both `avatar` and `info`, `width: 30% and 40%` . I don't want to use bootstrap for this purpose as it complicates things and I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: did not get your point? i can see 2 div left to image, then what is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `table-cell` how @w3debugger suggested or you can take advantage of a quick css hack to align vertically:

```
.yourclass{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

But that needs the parent of `.yourclass` to be `position:relative` and be of type `display:block;` If your parent is block it will take the height of the block that is inside it, so the avatar, that is next to `.yourclass` needs to be `display:block` as well,

I edited your example:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pBcut2e.jpg" />
    </div><div class="info">
        <div class="name">Important person here </div>
        <div class="position">CHIEF DIGITAL STRATEGIST &amp CO-FOUNDER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    width: 500px;
    background: aqua;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;  
    position: relative;
}
.avatar img {
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.info{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 40px;


  width: 70%;

  position:absolute;
  right: 0;

  vertical-align: top;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)

}
```

Live preview:

https://jsbin.com/gogewefizo/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `vertical-align` didn't work with `float` elements. You should use `display: table-cell` or `display: inline-block in order to meet your requirements.

Please check the code below.

```css
.header {
  width: 500px;
  background: aqua;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: table;
}
.avatar img {
  width: 150px;
}
.avatar,
.info {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pBcut2e.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="name">Important person here</div>
    <div class="position">CHIEF DIGITAL STRATEGIST &amp CO-FOUNDER</div>
  </div>

</div>
```